# The difference between of and by

Tags: prepositions

What is correct?

> painting by Leonardo

or

> Painting of Leonardo

Can the two propositions in this particular context be used interchangeably?

---

Added Context:

In a book I have found: the four portraits of Leonardo were painted on wooden panel, where the name of the book is ***Paintings of Leonardo da Vinci***.

What if the name of the book would have been ***Paintings by Leonardo Da Vinci***. Then should it be

- The four portraits by Leonardo were painted on wooden panel

?

Comment: And what is the particular context?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience; actually In a book I have found: the four portraits of Leonardo were painted on wooden panel, where the name of the book: Paintings of Leonardo da Vinci. What if the name of the book would have been "Paintings by Leonardo Da Vinci". The four portraits by Leonardo were painted on wooden panel.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little difference. Since you didn't mention the particular context, I can only mention the basic difference.

If you want to refer to all of the Leonardo's works you should say

> Paintings of Leonardo

However, if you want to refer to a single work, you should say

> A painting by Leonardo

---

In line with the added info:

The book title is ***paintings of Leonardo da Vinci*** because it's probably about all of the paintings that he has painted. If the book was about only four specific paintings out of all, then the title would be as you suggested.

Note that if you want to refer to some works (or one work as I initially said above) you should use "by" rather than "of", which this does not have any thing to do with the title directly in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Both phrases are correct, but they have different meanings

> A painting **of** Leonardo

is a painting where Leonardo is the *subject* of the painting

> A painting **by** Leonardo

is a painting where Leonardo is the artist.

If you wanted to refer to the body of work by the artist

> The paintings **of** Leonardo